# For (Z,+), let A=<a>, B=<b>, where a, b are positive integers. What is A∩B and why?

Tags: abstract-algebra

For (Z,+), let A=(a), B=(b), where a, b are positive integers. What is A∩B and why? (I am using () to mean cyclic group <>, since the system does allow me to use <>.)

I guess A∩B=(lcm(a,b)) (cyclic group), so I need to show A∩B⊆(lcm(a,b)) and (lcm(a,b))⊆A∩B.

I am wondering how to do the first part.

And for the second part, I have:
Let x∈(lcm(a, b))=(ka)=(lb), where k, l∈Z --> x = lcm(a, b)^p= (ka)^p=kap=(lb)^p = lbp --> x=kap∈A=(a) and x= lbp ∈B=(b) --> x∈A∩B -> (lcm(a, b))⊆ A∩B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for the first part, you can let $x\in A\cap B$. Then by definite there exists positive integers $k_1,k_2$ such that $x=k_1a=k_2b$. Note that $a|x$ and $b|x$. This gives us that $lcm(a,b)|x$. Hence $A\cap B$ is a subset of $(lcm (a,b) )$.

The second part follows immediately from the definition of lcm.